# Input inside a label container, width isse

Tags: css, display

How to stretch the input field in a labeled container to fill it entirely. Space for the name of the label has to be taken into account. I'm trying to do it without using the flex-box.

```css
label {
  display: block;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
}

input {
  display:? width:?
}
```

```html
<label for="name--expense" class="name--expense">
Name:<input type="text" id="name--expense" />
```

Comment: label {
            display: flex;
            line-height: 2.5rem;
        }

        input {
            width: 100%;
        }     <label for="name--expense" class="name--expense">Name:
        <input type="text" id="name--expense" />
    </label> check it

Answer (score 0):

add this to css and close label too.
input { width: 70%; }

Comment: just add a code snippet with some explanation